# SQL queries across joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

In MySQL I have three tables:

- `Customer`: which contains `ID`, `Name`, `Balance`, and `Address`
- `Orders`: which contains the `Order ID`, `Order Date`, `Shipping Date`, and `Customer ID` as a foreign key
- `Order Lines`: which contains `Order ID`, `Part ID`, and `Number Ordered`.

I'm trying to write a query such that I can figure out how many items each customer has ordered, but I'm not sure how to get discrete sums for each of the customers. The sample code I have so far just sums all the order lines together into one field.

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(customer_last_name, ', ', customer_first_name) AS 'Customer',
  SUM(number_ordered) AS 'Ordered'
FROM Customers t1
  JOIN Orders t2
    ON t1.Customer_id=t2.Customer_id
  JOIN order_lines t3
    ON t2.order_id=t3.order_id;
```

I'm pretty new to SQL and coding in general, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as concerns, you just need to add a `group by` clause to that query to make it produce the result you want:

```
select 
    concat(c.last_name, ', ', c.first_name) as customer
    sum(oi.number_ordered) as ordered
from customers c
join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
join order_lines oi on oi.order_id = o.order_id
group by c.id, c.last_name, c.first_name
```

This gives you one row per customer, along with the sum o `number_ordered` for all items they ordered.

Notes:

- the column aliases should not be surrounded with single quotes (which stand for string litterals); usually no quoting is needed, unless the indentifier contains special characters, in which case you can use backticks
- *meaningful* table aliases make the query easier to read and maintain